# ATmega32's TIMER1 isn't giving an interrupt when matching

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I am working on a project and I have two external interrupts (push buttons) and using TIMER1 compare match mode, I want the timer to reach the top value twice (here I have it one time only because I was trying to see where's the problem) then turn off a dc motor but it doesn't seem to fire the interrupt, the external interrupts work btw, I even tried to toggle a led in the ISR and it won't do anything. Here's the code:

```c
    uint8 volatile flag=0; //for stopping the motor
      void INT0_init(void)
       {
                MCUCR  = MCUCR | (1<ISC01) ; /*interrupt with rising edge */
                MCUCR = MCUCR | (1<<ISC00);
                 GICR |= (1<<INT0);
                DDRD   = DDRD & (~(1<<PD2)); /* setting PD2 as input pin */
       }
    ISR (INT0_vect)
    {
        
        SET_BIT(PORTB, PB3); //when the interrupt happens the motor moves in anti clockwise direction
        CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, PB4);
        TIMER1_ctcMode(0x0000, 0xFFFF);
        while( PIND & (1<<PD2) ) {} /*to stay in this state as long as it got pressed once */
    
    }
    void INT1_init(void)
    {
        MCUCR  = MCUCR | (1<ISC11) ; /*interrupt with rising edge */
        MCUCR = MCUCR | (1<<ISC10);
        GICR |= (1<<INT1);
        DDRD   = DDRD & (~(1<<PD3)); /* setting PD3 as input pin */
    
    }
    ISR (INT1_vect)
    {
        SET_BIT(PORTB, PB3); //when the interrupt happens the motor moves in clockwise directio
        CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, PB4);
        TIMER1_ctcMode(0x0000, 0xFFFF); //call the timer for 8-ish seconds
        while( PIND & (1<<PD3) ) {} /*to stay in this state as long as it got pressed once */
        
    
    
    }
    ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect) //timer isr
    {
        flag++;
        PORTA ^=(1<<0);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        SET_BIT(SREG,7);    /* setting the i-bit */
        SET_BIT(DDRB, PB3); //setting the pins as output pins of the H-bridge
        SET_BIT(DDRB, PB4);
        TIMER1_initCtcMode();
        INT0_init();        /* initializing interrupt0 */
        INT1_init();        /*initializing interrupt1 */
    
        while (1)
        {
            if(flag==1)
                {
    
                    TIMER1_deinit(); // to stop the timer
                    CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, PB3); //when the timer finishes counting stop the motor
                    CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, PB4);
                    flag=0;                 //set the flag to zero for the next time the timer is used
                }
    
        }
    }
```

and here's the timer configuration:

```c
    void TIMER1_initCtcMode(void)
    {
            SREG= SREG | (1<<7); //setting the i-bit
            TIMSK |=(1<<OCIE1A); //setting interrupt enable for timer1
            TIFR &=~(1<<OCF1A);
            TCCR1A |=(1<<FOC1A) ;
            TCCR1A |= (1<<FOC1B); //setting the non-pwm bits
            TCCR1B |=(1<<WGM12);
            TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12);
            TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10); //setting prescalar at 1024
            TCCR1B  = TCCR1B &( ~(1<<CS11));
            TCCR1A &= ~(1<<COM1A0); //clearing them for non-pwm mode
            TCCR1A &= ~(1<<COM1A1);
    
    
    }
    void TIMER1_ctcMode(volatile uint16 initialValue, volatile uint16 topValue)
    {
        TCNT1=initialValue; //initial value
        OCR1A=topValue; //top value to reach 8.3sec
    }
    void TIMER1_deinit(void)
    {
        CLEAR_BIT(TCCR1B, CS12);
        CLEAR_BIT(TCCR1B, CS10);
        CLEAR_BIT(TCCR1B, CS11);
        TCNT1=0;
        OCR1A=0;
        TIMSK &=~(1<<OCIE1A);
    }
```

Comment: `delay_ms()` in the ISR is ringing alarm bells for a start.  Is there any particular reason to use `TIMER1_COMPA` rather than `TIMER1_OVF`?  You have `flag++` in the ISR but `flag == 1` in the main thread - safer to test `flag != 0`.

Comment: @Clifford I am sorry but there's no TCCR1C in ATmega32, i am using the delay within the ISR just to toggle the led, it's not a part of the project and i want the flag to be equal to 2 not one in the while(1) loop but i was just testing once again, and the led within the ISR isn't toggling in the simulation and i can't figure out why. thanks in advance

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention which ATmega you are using, and they are not all the same.  You should fix that.

Comment: You don't need the delay, the LED changing state either way would indicate that the interrupt occurred. You should still test for > or >= rather than ==.

Comment: @Clifford i removed the delay and checked for >= and it still doesn't work

Comment: I would not expect that change to make it "work"; it was just a flaw in the design, not the problem.  You still have not edited the question with the essential information (the actual part number). I am addressing your issue by inspecting the datasheet, and clearly I am not looking at the right one.  Leaving the information in a comment is not sufficient.  SO is not a discussion forum.